# Unable to edit map in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, editing, objectid

For some reason I am unable to edit my map in ArcGIS. When I click 'start editing' on the editor toolbar, I get the following error message:

[image: Editing Issue]

I've ensured that my field names in the Excel table don't have any spaces or special characters. I've also tried adding an ObjectID field, but it won't recognize this.I'm specifically looking to draw lines on the map and write labels to identify certain urban districts.

Comment: What kind of data is in the E:\PHD path?  If you want to draw lines, you'll need to create a feature class first - shapefile or file geodatabase feature class.  Where do the Excel tables come in to play?  Do they have point coordinates?

Comment: It's an Excel spreadsheet with various fields and point co-ordinates. Another problem is that I'm unable to export the data once I've added it to ArcMap: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116627/unable-to-export-data-to-shapefile-in-arcgis

Comment: You can't edit an Excel spreadsheet (even with coordinates) in ArcMap. To draw lines, you need to first create a new polyline feature class. (Alternatively, you can use the Draw tools to create graphics which can then be converted into features.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should check your all files location and make sure that all files are in .shp format and also remember one thing that you can not edit any excel sheet without converting it in to .shp file.
if again you face such a similar problem then create a GDB and export all layers in GDB,after that you can edit it and also make sure your Arcmap should be in Data view not in Layout view.

Answer (score 0):

Export your table into a .gdb or as a .dbf, the ObjectID field will be added, and you can commence editing.

If it's a feature class, similarly export into a .gdb or as a shapefile

Comment: That's another problem I have - I'm unable to export the table! http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116627/unable-to-export-data-to-shapefile-in-arcgis

Comment: try with the default name it gives you, Export_output what not, still not working?

Comment: Nope, it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to edit event layer created from XY coordinates excelsheet? 
Try first to export the event layer to shapefile (or feature class into geodatabase).